# Installing programs to LiveCD/USB?

Tags: installation, live-usb, live-cd, iso, persistence

I want to have an Ubuntu LiveCD or LiveUSB with a program (Cisco Packet Tracer) installed on it that’s always there every time I boot.

Anyone knows how to do this?

(Preferably as an image as I want this on several USB-sticks, but maybe I can also do some kind of clone if I succeed on one.)

Thanks! 
Magnus

Comment: You can make a persistent live drive with mkusb, or you can download a compressed image of such a drive and extract it to a USB drive (or memory card). See these links, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Compressed_image_file_with_a_persistent_live_system

Answer (score 0):

With live CD there is no easy way to do it, however if you install ubuntu on a USB, you will be able to install any application on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your USB stick using the Startup Disc Creator there is an option to create extra space for persistent data. If you do that then you can install Cisco Packet Tracer and this will be available next time you boot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could either install the program every time you run Ubuntu Live, using another drive/partition and a quick install script, something like "sudo dpkg --install program.deb" should work.

Like another answer said, using a USB with "persistent" would work too, but be aware there was a bug in the persistence where after several reboots (took me a few weeks of daily boots to see it) where the persistent data would get corrupted. It was existing in some debian bug reports since 2007 or so, and still there in 2011. And of course, a CD would need a separate drive/partition to save the persistent data.

Or you could remaster a new Ubuntu Live ISO/CD/USB, a tool like remastersys should work, and there are other tools to do that too, but I don't know which are "easier" or "best".